# Rails - associate two different fields from one model as one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have two fields on my Game model, home_team_id and away_team_id.

I would like to associate these two fields as the teams tied to the Game.

These teams can belong to more than one game so I have on my Team model

```
has_many :games
```

I'm not sure what to put on my Game model.

```
has_many :teams
```

doesn't work because it doesn't know to look for home_team_id and away_team_id. Is there a way to tell it that there are two different keys for teams?

I've also tried this but it doesn't work either.

```
has_one :away_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'id'
has_one :home_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'id'
```

In the end I just want to be able to run @game.teams in the console and get the home and away teams returned.

Comment: You can define a method `teams` in the game model and return the away_team and home_team in an array.

Comment: would I be able to use this method in the console to calls on a game record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have created your Game migration like:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :home_team_id
      t.integer :away_team_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can archive it by specifying your model like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: 'away_team_id'
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team', foreign_key: 'home_team_id'

  def teams
    [away_team, home_team]
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. As simple as I was hoping too, thanks!

Comment: @kubum how do you call the inverse of this? `Team.find(1).games` results in the following exception: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: games.team_id: SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."team_id" = ? LIMIT ?)`

Comment: @JoeEssey I haven't been using Rails for years already, it is hard to see how did you define the relation in "Team" model, but you would have to make it to look in both columns: away and home.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find this a little bit useful:

Migration for games:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.date :match_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Migration for teams:

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Model `Game`:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team"

  # helper for teams
  def teams
    [home_team, away_team]
  end
end
```

Add references

```
class AddReferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :home_team_id
      t.integer :away_team_id
    end
  end
end
```

In console:

```
Team.new(name: 'foo').save

Team.new(name: 'bar').save

Game.new(home_team: Team.first, away_team: Team.last).save

Game.first
# => #<Game id: 1, match_date: nil, created_at: "2013-11-20 21:53:41", updated_at: "2013-11-20 21:53:41", home_team_id: 1, away_team_id: 6>

Game.first.teams
# => [#<Team id: 1, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-11-20 21:40:19", updated_at: "2013-11-20 21:40:19">, #<Team id: 2, name: "bar", created_at: "2013-11-20 21:53:12", updated_at: "2013-11-20 21:53:12">]
```

Comment: This works. My associations needed to be belongs_to and I needed to define the teams array. Thanks.